# Prove the Contrapositive by Cases - Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am given

Prove that every prime number greater than $3$ is either one more or one less than a multiple of $6$.

I am showing a set of integers

$S=\{,5,7,11,13,17,19,23, ...$sequence A000040 in the OEIS$ \}$

and it says a multiple of 6 either one or more so,

$6n-1$ or $6n+1$

Proving it by a contrapositive and by cases is the question

Comment: Its divisible by 7...So Its not a prime!

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?  For instance, can you state the contrapositive?  And then...?

Comment: So, by the quotient remainder theorem, the possibilities for an integer $x$ is that it is of the form $6n, 6n+1, 6n+2, 6n+3, 6n+4,$ or $6n+5$ (*note that $6n+5=6(n+1)-1$ is a number of the form one less than a multiple of six*).  Can you say anything about one or more of the divisors of numbers of the form $6n,6n+2,6n+3,6n+4$?

Comment: I can use $6n+l$ where $l \leq 5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime number bigger than $5.$ Thus we can write it as

$$p=6n+r$$ where $r\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}.$

Of course if $r\in \{0,2,4\}$ then the number is even and so not a prime number (since we assume $>5$).

Of course if $r=3$ then the number is a multiple of $3$ and so not a prime number.

Thus $r\in\{1,5\}.$ That is $$p=6n+1$$ or $$p=6n+5=6(n+1)-1.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! This is getting me into how proofs are formulated. Thanks again!!